# Is there a nonlinear optical material that absorbs visible light stronger with increasing intensity independent of its wavelength?

Tags: optics, non-linear-optics, optical-materials

One of the main shortcomings of digital image sensors is the quite "unnatural" behaviour for rendering highlights compared to film (and the human eye, I guess). Typically, with increasing intensity the image is quickly clipping while film material shows a much smoother transition to the brightest point.

My question is, if there is an optical material that would allow to reduce the intensity of the brightest areas and thus doing an optical compression of dynamic range. So the absorption of light should ideally be depending only on the intensity, not the wavelength and grow with increasing intensity. I guess this is not so easy, because otherwise camera manufacturers would have included that to their products. But maybe someone has an idea. Perhaps a combination of different fluorescent materials absorbing visible light and emitting in the infrared spectrum (which then could be filtered)?

Comment: I don't know if such a material, but in case of a camera it wouldn't need to have the same properties over the whole visible range. There could be 3 different materials for the red, green and blue part of a pixel, each only having the same properties for a smaller range of colors.

Comment: Yes, maybe as part of a Bayer filter directly on the the image sensor. I was thinking more about a filter solution to apply to an existing camera.

Comment: may I add, being a photography fan and an optics physicist, that I do not think this to be a problem. With my photography I clearly make the distinction: if digital, meter for highlights; if film, meter for shadows. Nowadays technology is already at such a great place either way, that consumer cameras have >10EV of dynamic range for a single exposure and that value has been increasing year after year as sensor technology evolves. Of course that at some point we will have 14+ EV sensors, but which technology will lead to that, I do not know.

Comment: And another thing, for photography, nonlinear effects will be problematic as the light intensity is incredibly low. It is already amazing the quantum efficiency and low noise current sensors have and manufacturers take that into advantage, and pushing users to expose for highlights as shadows will be low noise and with enough info to be stretched.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly doubt it's possible, because (other than mechanical "light traps" like baffles) photon absorption is a quantum process.  As you may know, there are a number of compounds which demonstrate significant, nonlinear, changes in absorptivity for a given wavelength.
A 'saturable absorber' will have low transmissivity until the photon density reaches a certain threshold, at which point the material moves to an excited state and the transmissivity goes near to 1.0.  Rarer are 'saturable transmitters' which start out transmitting but switch to blocking (low transmission) when excited.

Because those processes depend on specific electron level transition energies,  this approach cannot work for white light.

I'm skipping the extreme case where the thermal absorption leads to oxidizing (i.e. burning/charring), which I suppose you could look at as absorption increasing.

Comment: How about a material where two-photon absorption can excite charge carriers into the (broad) conduction band?

Comment: Yes, that's of course true, absorption will by definition only happen for certain wavelengths. And the effect might typically even be decreasing with increasing light intensity?

Comment: @A.P., just from quickly reading a bit about the two-photon absorption: The effect seems to be nonlinear to the intensity, but sill decreasing with increasing intensity?

Comment: @JosefR No, it will increase with intensity. The higher the intensity, the higher the chances of 2 photons hitting the nonlinear material at the same time.